# Where can I find the raw stats data of the current bitcoin network?

Tags: network

So that I can build something like [this](http://www.bitcoincharts.com/bitcoin/) and [this](http://www.bitcoincharts.com/charts/) in PHP? Is there any official data feed or do I have to go through the entire network programatically to get them?

Answer (score 2):

There's APIs like https://blockexplorer.com/q/ which provide the information, or you can just collect it yourself from your own `bitcoind`. Most of it is fairly straightforward, but there's a few which you need to do some analysis on if you generate it yourself (like difficulty estimation).